# Map of List: Sum all the values of the list class

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, java-stream

I have this class

```
public Car(Colour colour, int passengers) {
    this.colour = colour;
    this.passengers = passengers;
}
```

Where Colour is an enum:

```
   public enum Colour {
    RED, YELLOW, GREEN, BLACK, WHITE, BLUE, GREY
}
```

I have created this map:

```
Map<Colour, List<Car>> colourListMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Imagine we populate the map of lists:

```
Car yellowCar = new Car(Colour.YELLOW, 4);
Car blueCar = new Car(Colour.BLUE, 1);
Car blackCar = new Car(Colour.BLACK, 3);

Map<Colour, List<Car>> map = carMemory.addCarByColour(yellowCar);
carMemory.addCarByColour(blueCar);
carMemory.addCarByColour(blackCar);
```

As well with 2 instances of the same colour:

```
Car redCar = new Car(Colour.RED, 2);
Car redCar2 = new Car(Colour.RED, 6);
Map<Colour, List<Car>> map = carMemory.addCarByColour(redCar);
carMemory.addCarByColour(redCar2);
```

Is there a simple way to sum all the passengers from the Car class? Instead to call the key by Colour? I was thinking to Java 8 Stream... but I m not very confident.

I know this isn't correct.

```
int size =  map.values()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(Collection::size)
                .sum();
```

Comment: Do you need a sum of `passengers` for each color or simply sum all of the `passengers` for all cars in the map?

Comment: All the passengers

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko could you please put as well the way filtered by colour?

Comment: which colors have to be filtered out?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko one of your choice after will be the same for the other colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a sum of all the passengers for all cars in the map that will do the job:

```
            map.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream of car objects
                .mapToInt(Car::getPassengers)
                .sum();
```

Example for filtering colors:

```
           map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == Colour.RED ||
                                 entry.getKey() == Colour.BLACK) // only entries for BLACK and RED will remain
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // Stream<List<Car>>
                .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Car>
                .mapToInt(Car::getPassengers)
                .sum();
```

**Side note:**

- instead of `HashMap` for a Map with enum-keys use [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html), this special-purpose implementation is designed to be used only with enums and has better performance.

Comment: I didn't know about EnumMap, thank you so much.